# Cropping UIImage fails

Tags: swift, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, crop, cgimage

I'm trying to crop an image from UIImagePicker to a specific rect, but I receive dark colors instead of an image (which seems to be the color themes of the image).

First my imagePicker function:

```
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
         let originalImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        if originalImage == nil { print("Error Not Found An Image")}
            imageView.image = originalImage
            let croppedImage = cropImage(image: originalImage, rect: CGRect(x: 0.13, y: 0.12, width: 0.74, height: 0.75))
            imageView.image = croppedImage
}
```

And my crop function

```
    func cropImage (image: UIImage, rect: CGRect) -> UIImage {

        let resImage = CIImage(image: image, options: [:])
        let croppedImage = resImage?.cropped(to: rect)
        let img = UIImage(ciImage: croppedImage!, scale: 1, orientation: image.imageOrientation)

        return img
    }
```

Comment: Why do you give values that are less than 1 for the crop rect? Try giving a more higher value for both width and height.

Comment: The values of the rect are out of 1. so 0.2 is a fifth of the x axis. But I changed that and I still having the same color images

Comment: Try this link: https://medium.com/@joehattori/cropping-images-in-swift-and-the-basics-of-uiimage-cgimage-and-ciimage-42608e4531bb

Comment: That's right the problem was with values of the rect. They were too small

Comment: Yeah. Awesome. So it’s solved now right?

Comment: Yeah, it's solved. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the values of the rect. In my case they were simply too small.

Thanks  badhanganesh for the hint